# UITableViewCell With Url

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an application that involves a taleview adn a custom tableviewcell. I am using three arrays in my tableviewcontroller to show in the tableview. Once the user selects that row then it takes them to a url according to the urlArray I created. This worked perfectly fine until I implemented a search inside the tableview and then when I search the tableview and click on a cell is goes to the third or fourth url inside my array and that would be the wrong url.

Here is my code for the tableviewcontroller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var arrUrlName = ["https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL?q=aapl?q=AAPL?q=AAPL","https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/GOOG?q=goog?q=GOOG?q=GOOG","https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/FB?q=fb?q=FB?q=FB","https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AMZN?q=amzn?q=AMZN?q=AMZN"]
    var stockNames = ["Apple Inc.","Google Inc.","Facebook Inc.","Amazon"]
    var symbolArray = ["AAPL","GOOG","FB","AMZN"]

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    var filteredData: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filteredData = stockNames

        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredData.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StockTableViewCell

        let arrayName =  filteredData[indexPath.row]
        let arraySymbol = symbolArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.stockNameLabel?.text = arrayName
        cell.symbolLabel?.text = arraySymbol

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let urlName = self.arrUrlName[indexPath.row]
        let url = URL(string: urlName)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data

        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredData = stockNames
        } else {
            // The user has entered text into the search box
            // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
            // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
            // item should NOT be included
            filteredData = stockNames.filter({(dataItem: String) -> Bool in
                // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
                if dataItem.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are filtering `stockNames`, but leaving `arrUrlName` and `symbolArray` unfiltered. After row is selected, you are picking wrong url here:

```
let urlName = self.arrUrlName[indexPath.row]
```

because indexes of `stockNames` and `arrUrlName` are not in sync anymore.

**Recommended** **solution:**

Easiest way to fix this is to reorganize you data in single a single array.
First, create structure

```
struct TableItem {
    let url: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
}
```

then, reorganize your data in single array like

```
let data = [
   TableItem(
      url: "https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL?q=aapl?q=AAPL?q=AAPL",
      name: "Apple Inc.",
      symbol: "AAPL"
   ),
   TableItem(
      url: "https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/GOOG?q=goog?q=GOOG?q=GOOG",
      name: "Google Inc.",
      symbol: "GOOG"
   ),
   TableItem(
      url: "https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/FB?q=fb?q=FB?q=FB",
      name: "Facebook Inc.",
      symbol: "FB"
   ),
   TableItem(
      url: "https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AMZN?q=amzn?q=AMZN?q=AMZN",
      name: "Amazon",
      symbol: "AMZN"
    )
]
```

Set initial `filteredData`

```
var filteredData = data
```

Fill cell data in `cellForRowAt:` with:

```
let item = filteredData[indexPath.row]

cell.stockNameLabel?.text = item.name
cell.symbolLabel?.text = item.symbol
```

Fixed filtering:

```
filteredData = data.filter { $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

so method become:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredData = data
    } else {
        filteredData = data.filter { $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
    }
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

This way symbols and urls are going to be filtered too.

In `didSelectRowAt:` you can get your url:

```
let item = filteredData[indexPath.row]
let url = URL(string: item.url)
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I am getting an error when calling the let filtered. It is saying unresolved identifier "searchText." Do I have to call that variable or what. @XeNoN

Comment: I am getting two more errors inside of the SearchBar code. They are "Could not assign Value Type. And "Could not invoke 'filter' with an argument type. @XeNoN

Answer (score 1):

You need to organize your data better. Instead of three separate arrays, have one array. Each element of the array should either be a dictionary with the three values or better yet, a `struct` with three properties.

This makes it much easier to sort and filter your data for the table view.

Comment: What rmaddy says. (I was about to compose an answer saying the same thing but he beat me to it.) Maintaining multiple arrays and keeping them sorted/filtered together is difficult and error-prone. Don't do that.